# APEX: How to Submit page when 'Enter' pressed on field

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page with one field only. How can user submit the page by pressing 'Enter' without having to click the 'Submit' button? User should therefore be able to either press 'Enter' or click 'Submit'. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

APEX text items have a property "Submit when Enter pressed".  Set this to Yes and you are almost done. The APEX request is set to the name of the item so that you can, if you need to, have submit processing that depends on this e.g. PL/SQL Condition:

```
 :request in ('SUBMIT','P1_MY_TEXT_ITEM')
```

Comment: Thank you, Tony. Where do I set the APEX request?

Comment: The APEX request is automatically set to the name of the item, I don't think you can change it.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I put ":request in ('SAVE','P5_VALUE')" in the Server-side Condition -> PL/SQL Expression field of the Process that saves rows. I could tell the 'SAVE' part was working, but it still wont trigger when I put a value in "P5_VALUE" and press enter. I do have that field set to submit on enter.

Comment: @EdHayes3 That's odd. If you can recreate your issue on apex.oracle.com then I can take a look, see what you've missed.

Answer (score 1):

What is your APEX version ?

If you are using APEX 4, you can try this JQuery code :

```
$('#YOUR_TEXTFIELD_ID').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '13')
        $('#YOUR_BUTTON').trigger('click');
});
```

It works only if any onclick event has been defined for the button, else simply call apex.submit(...) instead.